# What is the best location for storing logfiles generated by 3rd party assemblies on IIS running an aspnet mvc app

Tags: iis, logging

The asp.net mvc web application generates log-files and cache files within an 3rd party assembly. I only can modify the path, where the assembly puts the files.

Where can I store the files on the server, without giving the asp.net-User to many privilegs.

What is the best directory to store them in?

Thank you

Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Root log dir

---- log app 1

---- log app 2

Create specific user with only read permission